# How to enable autocomplete of HTML tags within .js files for JSX for Atom?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, atom-editor, jsx

I would like to be able to use autocomplete for html tags in my React/JSX code. The same way it works for html files. Can I configure Atom to enable tags autocomplete for JSX files? Thanks

Comment: https://atom.io/packages/react ?

Comment: I have that package installed, but html within JSX is still not autocompleting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-react/issues/12#issuecomment-173223639

> I would suggest using https://atom.io/packages/language-babel, this already includes React JSX (tag autocompletion) plus es2015 goodies :) AND it also supports facebook's flow grammar out of the box! And after i install this package, i disable the default language-javascript package that you get from Atom when you first install it